# how to visualize a simple text in rviz?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to display a simple text in rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342250/how-to-visualize-a-simple-text-in-rviz?/) by [crazyRan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50947/crazyran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-22**:
Could you tell us what you've already found and tried yourself?

We're here to help, but not to do (all) of the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a RViz marker for that, take a look:  http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#View-Oriented_Text_.28TEXT_VIEW_FACING.3D9.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D

And here a publisher example: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#The_Marker_Message

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2020-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazyRan](https://answers.ros.org/users/50947/crazyran/) on 2020-01-22**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-03**:
Related, for overlaying text on the screen instead: https://answers.ros.org/question/341944/display-text-in-rviz/